# Two very close floating point numbers are not equal

Tags: ruby, floating-point

In IRB:

```
0.9999999999999998 == 1.0
# => false
0.99999999999999998 == 1.0
# => true
```

Also just showing the `inspect` values:

```
0.9999999999999998
# => 0.9999999999999998
0.99999999999999998
# => 1.0
```

In my case the value created by my program is unfortunately the first one, so I'm having trouble writing a test case which validates the value as equal to one.

I am deciding between the following options:

1. add `round` calls in the application code, however the application is already working, I just am unable to test
2. add `round` calls in the testing code
3. ???

What would be your recommended approach? Is there a way I can configure my program to treat 0 with fifteen nines after the decimal as equal to 1.0? It feels a bit frustrating because sixteen nines after the decimal seems to be the cut off - I'm only one short.

Comment: You've shown that IRB is interpreting decimal floating-point values as type Float, which has fixed precision, as opposed to type BigDecimal, which has arbitrary precision.  That says little about what your program does or should do, or about what your tests do or should do.

Comment: Note, too, that it is rarely appropriate to perform exact (in)equality comparisons of floating-point numbers.  Using arbitrary-precision numbers doesn't really change that.  If you want specific advice, then you'll need to clarify exactly what the predicate is that you want to test.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I am wondering if there is a way I can configure Float in such a way that `0.9999999999999998 == 1.0`. Like I said it seems like this value (15 nines) is only one off from the precision I need (16 nines). I've started to look at the constants in the [Float](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Float.html) class - I tried changing `EPSILON` and `DIG` but it didn't have an effect.

Comment: No, @maxpleaner, you cannot adjust the precision of Float.  It is tied to the characteristics of the machine's hardware and ABI.

Comment: _"the value created by my program is unfortunately the first one"_ – maybe you shouldn't use floats in the first place. How do you calculate that value?

Comment: @Stefan the float represents probability, so it can be 0.333333333 or 0.5, etc. Like I said in the question I realize I can use `round` in the application code.

Comment: [`Rational`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Rational.html) seems to be a better fit, e.g. `1/3r` or `1/2r`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading this article on how to compare small floating-point differences:
http://c-faq.com/fp/fpequal.html

I converted their proposed solutions to Ruby:

```
class Float
  MY_EPSILON   = 0.000000000000001
  MY_TOLERANCE = 0.000000000000001

  def eq_epsilon?(flt)
    a = self
    b = flt

    (a - b).abs <= MY_EPSILON * a.abs
  end

  def self.reldif(a, b)
    c = a.abs
    d = b.abs
    d = [c,d].max

    d == 0.0 ? 0.0 : (a - b).abs / d
  end

  def eq_reldif?(flt)
    Float.reldif(self, flt) <= MY_TOLERANCE
  end
end
```

And thus we can run some test code:

```
f1 = 0.99999999999999998
f2 = 0.9999999999999998
f3 = 0.999999999999998

[f1, f2, f3].each { |f|
  p f.eq_epsilon?(1.0)
  p 1.0.eq_epsilon?(f)
}

puts "--------------"

[f1, f2, f3].each { |f|
  p f.eq_reldif?(1.0)
  p 1.0.eq_reldif?(f)
}
```

With output:

```
true
true
true
true
false
false
--------------
true
true
true
true
false
false
```

However more testing is probably needed to make sure it satisfies all your requirements.